# Problem with add_p() from gtsummary package

Tags: gtsummary

When trying to run the following code:

```
ct1_1 <- df2 %>% 
  tbl_cross(row = prtvfde1, col = prtclfde, missing = "no") %>% 
  add_p(source_note = T,
        test = c(prtvfde1, prtclfde) ~ "fisher.test",
        test.args = "fisher.test" ~list(workspace=2e9))
```

I got the following error:

Error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: prtvfde1.
Caused by error:
! Error processing `test` argument for element 'prtvfde1'. Expecting a function or a string of
a function name.
Backtrace:

1. ... %>% ...
2. cli::cli_abort(., call = NULL)
3. rlang::abort(...)

Where is my missunderstanding? And thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, that is, data and code we can run on our machines